# Accessing string elements from an array generated by parse str; need an object

Tags: php

Through `Parse_str` I am generating getting an array of strings. I cant figure out how to access the individual elements of these despite hours reading here at SO. I keep getting errors at ever turn. How do I access these elements?

```
parse_str($form_data, $form_data_array);
```

I am taking in `$form_data` which is an query string and outputting it as an array.

If I

```
vardump($form_data_array)
```

I get -

```
array(6) { 
    ["Customer_FName"]=> string(3) "ted" 
    ["Customer_LName"]=> string(5) "smith" 
    ["Customer_MobileNumber"]=> string(12) "555-555-5555" 
    ["Customer_Email"]=> string(7) "e@e.com" 
    ["Reservation_Message"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["C_Preference_Notes"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

I see that this is an array of strings. Now how do I access this? I need to assign variables to each of the strings. Example - $customer_FName= the actual result above.

Then Ideally I would like this as an object instead of a string. I tired `json_decode(the variable here)` but it doesn't work giving me errors. I am lost.

Comment: have you tried using `$form_data_array["Customer_FName"]` to access "ted"?

Comment: yes thanks but didnt work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access it is by using the index from the array, as suggested in the comments:

```
var_dump($form_data_array["Customer_FName"]); // outputs string(3) "ted"
```

If for some reason you really want to have a single variable for each value, then this should do:

```
foreach($form_data_array as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value; // Yes, double dollar, to assign the value of the string $key to a variable
}

var_dump($Customer_FName); // outputs string(3) "ted". Notice the uppercased var name
```

And if you really need an object, then your best option is

```
$object = (object)$form_data_array;

var_dump($object->Customer_FName); // outputs string(3) "ted"
```

Comment: Your `foreach` replicates `extract()`.

Comment: Indeed, and the warning about untrusted input form post from https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php makes me remember that more checks should be applied here, in order to avoid overwriting of already defined variables.

Comment: Thank you very much. so extract is better or foreach in this instance? I am going to have more checks such as INSERT IGNORE etc, this is just the start of the code that I have been stuck on

Comment: Also all of these seem to output a string, not an object. Even the last example outputs string(3) "ted" is there  way to make it an object? I am placing this in MYSQL

Comment: I am not sure to understand what do you need. In my last example, the object is `$object`, who holds attributes with the scalar values from the form (`$object->Customer_FName`). To better understand your issue, could you provide an example on how do you insert the values in MySQL and what kind of objects are required?